# Search into multidimensional array and change value of one key

Tags: php

I have one json request which contain multiple array:

```
{
  "user_type": "2",
  "user_id": "57",
  "client_detail": [
    {
      "server_user_id": "1",
      ........
      ........
      "is_active": "1",
      "client_local_id": "11"
    },
    {
      "server_user_id": "2",
      ........
      ........
      "is_active": "1",
      "client_local_id": "12"
    }
  ], 
  }
```

Using above request I change data into database. then return data from DB. but i have to pass `client_local_id` into response.

so suppose i got 3 result from DB then i have to return client_local_id(this field is not stored in DB, there is no need for that) with them. so i pass default client_local_id 0.

exa:

```
"client_detail": [
{
  "server_user_id": "1",
  ........
  ........
  "is_active": "1",
  "client_local_id": 0
},
{
  "server_user_id": "2",
  ........
  ........
  "is_active": "1",
  "client_local_id": 0
},
{
  "server_user_id": "3",
  ........
  ........
  "is_active": "1",
  "client_local_id": 0
},
]
```

then using below code i change value of client_local_id.

```
    $response = array('client_detail' => $dbvalue);
    /* Change Client Local ID */
    if(sizeof($client_detail_data)>0)
    {
        foreach($client_detail_data as $key=>$resclient_data)  // loop of request
        {
            foreach($response['client_detail'] as $key1=>$res_client)  //loop of response
            {
                //if id is match then change value
                if($res_client['server_user_id']==$resclient_data['server_user_id'])
                {
                    $response['client_detail'][$key1]['client_local_id'] = $resclient_data['client_local_id'];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But i think there is easy method, to do that. I have a multiple array in request so i don't want to use too much foreach loop. so how to solve it in proper way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all let’s map `server_user_id`s to `client_user_id`s:

```
$s2c = array();
foreach($resclient_data as $item) {
  $s2c[$item['server_user_id']] = $item['client_user_id'];
}
```

Now we can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) directly on `$response`:

```
$response['client_detail'] = array_map(function($elem) use($s2c) {
  $elem['client_local_id'] = $s2c[$elem['server_local_id']];
  return $elem;
}, $response['client_detail']);
```

I diidn’t test the code, but hopefully the idea is clear.

Comment: Thanks @mudasobwa, I got my answer. but i am not able to get $s2c array value inside array_map.  to solve that problem i have to use `global` inside function.

Comment: It depends on scopes these function are declared. If you use them one by one, you’d better use [`use` keyword](http://blog.dubbelboer.com/2012/04/07/php-use-keyword.html) instead of global. Pls see updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifiction.